# Creating Base plot from a data set

Tags: r, plot, dataset

I need to get result as below image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Mldbnr1-avMFgzS1Y4d2lqYUk/view?usp=sharing

I have got a data set from the link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Mldbnr1-avLUg1REJRRzFUZU0/view?usp=sharing

Here is the code I have written so far but does not appear to be correct:

```
source("load_data.R")

plot1 <- function(data=NULL) {
  if(is.null(data))
    data <- load_data()

library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)  
with(data, plot(Voltage,Global_active_power,type="n"))
with(subset(data, Voltage>=250), points(Voltage,Global_active_power, col="black"))
with(subset(data, Voltage!=249), points(Voltage,Global_active_power, col="red"))
title(main="Global Active Power(Kilowatts) for Voltage >=249")
legend("topright", pch = 1, col=c("black","red"), legend = c("Voltage>=249 & <250","Voltage>=250"))

}
```

I am plotting Voltage data against GLobal_active_power data as seen on the graph for only Voltage >= 249

Please help and I thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `dat` is the dataset, try

```
clr <- ifelse(dat[,"Voltage"]<250, "black", "red")
plot(Global_active_power ~ Voltage, data=dat, col=clr, xlim=c(249,252))
legend("topright", legend=c("<250", ">=250"), col=clr, pch=1)
```

Slight change to match the expected result:

```
clr <- ifelse(data[,"Voltage"]<250, "black", "red")
plot(Global_active_power ~ Voltage, data=data, col=clr, xlim=c(249,252))
legend("topright", pch = 1, col=c("black","red"), legend = c("Voltage>=249 & <250","Voltage>=250"))
title(main="Global Active Power(Kilowatts) for Voltage >=249")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude. It really helps me. Though I changed your code only slightly to match my expected result:      <pre><code>                                                     
    clr <- ifelse(data[,"Voltage"]<250, "black", "red")
     plot(Global_active_power ~ Voltage, data=data, col=clr, xlim=c(249,252))
     legend("topright", pch = 1, col=c("black","red"), legend = c("Voltage>=249 & <250","Voltage>=250"))
     title(main="Global Active Power(Kilowatts) for Voltage >=249")
    }

Comment: Thanks so much for that. It's really helpful